# WP_Query returning undefinded

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I am trying to add a shortcode to my plugin that will query a custom post type and then output that post type, however WP_Query is for some reason returning undefined. I believe my arguments are valid, per the [WordPress code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/), but perhaps I'm missing something?

```
function shortcode_callback_function() {
$custom_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'name' => 'single-custom-post-slug'
    );

    $plugin__shortcode = new WP_Query($custom_args);

if ( $plugin__shortcode->have_posts() ) {
    while( $plugin__shortcode->have_posts() ) {
        $plugin__shortcode->the_post();
        ob_start();
        
        $customField = the_field('custom-field-from-custom-post'); ?>
<h1>Some title</h1>
<p><?php $customField; ?></p>
<?php
return ob_get_contents();


    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} 
}



add_shortcode('adbillboard', 'shortcode_callback_function');
```

In debug mode I am receiving an 'Undefined variable:' error for the $plugin__shortcode variable. Anything I'm missing here?

Edit: the automated 'your site is experiencing an error email showed this:
'Error message: syntax error, unexpected ''test-billboard'' '

Comment: Can you put your actual query args?

Comment: those are the actual ones, with the exception of 'name', which is actually 'test-billboard'